# Create SSDT objects (stored procedures etc.) only if a condition is met

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I am reworking an existing database to work with SSDT for version control and easier deployment after something changed.
For this i need to create stored procedures that only get created when another database is not existing on the local computer. These procedures will then get their data from a linked sql server, not the local one (virtual machines/testing environments got their own database and dont need these procedures using a linked database/server).

**The problem with SSDT is:** When you add a stored procedure to your database-project in visual studio, you can't use conditions (or t-sql statements in general?).

Is there another solution to this problem except setting the scripts build action to 'none' and referencing it in the post-deployment script, where i can use conditions? I'm pretty sure post-deployment objects won't show when using the schema compare tool which would be nice to have.

---

There is nothing fancy about the procedures or temp tables in general, the main problem is creating them **only if** a specific database does not exist on the local machine.

---

**Example of a stored procedure:**
(old script i'm currently reworking for SSDT)
(**XTSQL01** is the linked server in this case)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
USE [BI]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 
/* =================================================================================
  Author: [ - ] 
  Create date: [ 2019-09-17 ] 
  Description: [ procedure to fetch Stock Data from linked Steps to BI
==================================================================================== */

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[BI].[DS].[FETCH_STOCK_LINKED]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
  DROP PROCEDURE [DS].[FETCH_STOCK_LINKED]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [DS].[FETCH_STOCK_LINKED]
AS 
BEGIN 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @errNumber INT, @errSeverity INT, @errState INT, @errProc VARCHAR(500), @errLine INT, @errMsg VARCHAR(500);

    BEGIN TRY

        DELETE FROM [BI].[DS].[STOCK];

    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @errNumber = ERROR_NUMBER();
        SET @errSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
        SET @errState = ERROR_STATE();
        SET @errProc = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
        SET @errLine = ERROR_LINE();
        SET @errMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        
        INSERT INTO [BI].[DS].[ERRORDATA] (ERR_NUMBER, ERR_SEVERITY, ERR_STATE, ERR_PROCEDURE, ERR_LINE, ERR_MESSAGE, ERR_DATE)
        VALUES (@errNumber, @errSeverity, @errState, @errProc, @errLine, @errMsg, GETDATE());

    END CATCH

    BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO [BI].[DS].[STOCK] (ARTICLENUMBER, STOCKAMOUNT, STOCKVALUE, STOCKROOM)
        SELECT SUB.ARTICLENUMBER as ARTICLENUMBER, SUB.STOCKAMOUNT as STOCKAMOUNT, SUB.STOCKVALUE as STOCKVALUE, SUB.STOCKROOM as STOCKROOM
        FROM
        (
            SELECT I.S_ITEMNO as ARTICLENUMBER, SUM(SQ.N_ITEMQUANTITY) as STOCKAMOUNT, SUM(SQ.N_ITEMQUANTITY*I.N_AVGPURCHASE) as STOCKVALUE, SR.S_ABBREVIATION as STOCKROOM
            FROM [XTSQL01].[Steps].[sao].[STOCKQUANT] SQ WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN [XTSQL01].[Steps].[sao].[STOCKROOM_M] SR WITH (NOLOCK) ON SQ.I_STOCKROOM_M = SR.I_STOCKROOM_M
            LEFT JOIN [XTSQL01].[Steps].[sao].[ITEM_M] I WITH (NOLOCK) ON SQ.I_ITEM_M = I.I_ITEM_M
            WHERE SQ.DT_DELETED IS NULL 
            --AND SQ.I_STOCKROOM_M = 1
            GROUP BY I.S_ITEMNO, SR.S_ABBREVIATION
        ) SUB
        WHERE SUB.STOCKAMOUNT > 0

    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @errNumber = ERROR_NUMBER();
        SET @errSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
        SET @errState = ERROR_STATE();
        SET @errProc = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
        SET @errLine = ERROR_LINE();
        SET @errMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        
        INSERT INTO [BI].[DS].[ERRORDATA] (ERR_NUMBER, ERR_SEVERITY, ERR_STATE, ERR_PROCEDURE, ERR_LINE, ERR_MESSAGE, ERR_DATE)
        VALUES (@errNumber, @errSeverity, @errState, @errProc, @errLine, @errMsg, GETDATE());

    END CATCH   

END
GO
```

---

**Example of a temp table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [BI].[DS].[ORDERDATA_TEMP_DELETE]
(
    ORDERNUMBER decimal(28,0) NOT NULL
);
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate project for these procedures. So, let's say that your current project is named `ProjectA`. You need to create another project, let's say `ProjectA_ext` and add database reference in it for the `ProjectA` with the option `The same database`. In that case `ProjectA_ext` will have all the objects from `ProjectA` in addition with all objects from `ProjectA_ext`.

Another consideration is that I'm not sure that you need exactly like that. If you have problems with linked server, then you need to create synonyms for all external (3 and 4 part names) objects and use variables for external databases and/or linked servers.

Comment: That sounds like it's going in the right direction. I created a new project (like ProjectA_ext) in my solution and added the same database. Now the question is how to get conditions into this? For example:  

`if $(servername) != 'server1'  
--execute my linked server scripts`  

and how do i do this without pre-/post-deploy scripts (if possible)?

Comment: No, that's not possible. What linked scripts are you talking about?

Comment: .SQL files for creating stored procedures and jobs, as well as seeding tables with initial data. Those scripts may only be executed if there is no local db where they could get the data from. They need to get their data from a linked server in that case. So i am looking for a way to seperate those "linked scripts" from the rest of my ssdt project, since they may not be executed always.

Comment: for jobs and initial data you can create special variable, let's say `$(Prod)` and then in post script do something like `IF ($(Prod) = 1) BEGIN ... put your scripts there ... END` and then define different publish profiles for different environments

Comment: Yea that's what i did, i also called the scripts to create stored procedures and temporary tables in there, but i was hoping for a better way to do it. so it looks like i'm stuck with doing it this way?

Comment: It is hard to answer, but creating temp tables and stored procedures in the post script doesn't sound right. Please update the question with the script examples, in that way it would be easier to provide you better solution

Comment: For me it didn't sound or feel right too, that's why i asked this question in the first place. I updated my question yesterday and included the whole script for the procedure. This is what i have to rework into a format that works with SSDT. So everything above `create procedure` needs to be deleted.

Comment: is the problem that you don't want it to be included on all instances, or that it is yields errors in SSDT?

Comment: The main problem is that some procedures and jobs need to be changed (or only created) if the database is on a test environment server (inside a vm). But a bunch of procedures needed to be moved to postdeploy because they yielded errors for example when those procedures use SQLCMD variables (something like $(InitialDate)).

Comment: Variables shouldn't cause the error. You will get errors when using 3-4 parts named objects. To solve that you need to use synonyms or some kind of wrappers. Jobs are not supported by SSDT natively, so there is no other way. For different objects in different environments you need to create separate projects.

Comment: Maybe this isn't the best example, but i get multiple different errors when i want to use SQLCMD-variables that have `Build Action` set to `Build` [as you can see here](https://i.imgur.com/qJb2MxP.png).

Comment: You need to wrap the variable into quotes - `'$(VariableName)'`.

Answer (score 0):

If the database schema is modified in a post-deployment script, it will be considered drifted from the registered version, if you register the DAC after deployments. If you use a publish profile for your deployments, DAC registration is one of the options, but that happens at the end of the schema update, before the post-deployment script runs.

If you're trying to automate the deployments, it may help to write the post-deployment script so it changes the schema only on the first execution (e.g. idempotent). And then have a mechanism to re-deploy the same DACPAC immediately after to fix the DAC version and remove the drift.

There are sometimes a chicken and egg situation that requires some creative thinking and sometimes multiple releases to deploy some things first that a subsequent release must make use of.

Comment: @Dmitrij is correct that you should use Sql variables to reference linked servers. But there are also other things that can be done to help simplify what you're trying to do.